# What does this syntax : bool in the method mean?

Tags: php, syntax, php-7

I am using a package name [laravel-google-calander](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar) in one of my project . When i was checking with the codes of the package i find a method below with the syntax as :

```
public function exists(): bool
   {
       return $this->id != '';
   }
```

What does that `:` and `bool` represents in the method ? Is it the new syntax of php7 or any thing else ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the PHP 7 syntax for [return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration). It will ensure that the return value is a boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I have php version 7.0.10. in my machine . Bu i am getting `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'`  in the line where this method exist. Is it due to php version ??

Comment: @Drudge Yes, that means you're not using PHP 7. You probably have multiple versions of PHP on your machine.